# I can't select multiple items in dropdown list web VBA

Tags: html, vba, list, web-scraping, dropdown

I am trying to fill in a form from an intranet page.
I have managed to highlight the element from a dropdown list I want to select but not at the same time. I want to select three in list
Here's my code:

```
Sub GetLTRTable()

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "myurl"

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
    Loop


    Dim Fields As Object

    Set Fields = ie.Document.all.Item("ADFields")
        Fields.Checked = True

    Dim organization As Object

    Set organization = ie.Document.all.Item("Org")
        organization.selectedindex = 0
    Dim Modality As Object
        Set Modality = ie.Document.getElementsByName("Modality")(0)
        With Modality.Value = "'GDXE'"
             Modality.Value = "'ABUS'"
             Modality.Value = "'A&S'"
        End With

    ie.Document.getElementsByName("Action").Item(1).Click
```

Here's the source code (note that I have just put an extract since there are a lot of modalities):

```
<select name="Modality" multiple="" size="4"><option value="'ALL'" selected="">ALL</option>
<option value="'A&amp;S'">A&amp;S</option>
<option value="'ABUS'">ABUS</option>
<option value="'ACS'">ACS</option>
<option value="'ANES'">ANES</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for the help

Corentin

Comment: I rolled back your title edit - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use by value then use attribute = value css selectors

```
With ie.document
    .querySelector("[value='ABUS']").Selected = True
    .querySelector("[value='GDXE']").Selected = True
End With
```

This should prove a fast selector method.

Also, use a proper page wait:

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need to change the value of `Modality`, but set the options to "selected":

`Modality.getElementsByTagname("option").item(0).selected = "selected"`

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks again, it works. 
But it there a way to look for value itself such as " ' A&S ' " rather than counting which item is what ? Because there are a  roughly a hundred of them

Comment: I think you need more information in your option tags, such as the name or the id. Are you in control of the html itself? Otherwise you could loop over all options to check if the Value attribute or InnerText attribute is the same as one of your values.

Comment: Well I have found a way to get the number of the item 
I have copy paste the HTML code in excel ^^
Thanks Alex for the help