# Excel VBA multi-select from drop-down on IE web page

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to interact with an internal application that runs in IE. I know Selenium may be a better option, but I am trying to avoid downloading anything additional onto a work machine.
I need to select multiple values from a drop-down list, but cannot see how to do it. I can select single items by GetElementByID().Value = "B_A235" or GetElementByID().selectedIndex = 2, but cannot see how to select multiple items.
This is the item I am trying to select from; I have shortened the list for posting purposes.

```
<select name="ctl00$Content$listBusinessUnits$GroupedDropDown1$elvBUGrp" id="ctl00_Content_listBusinessUnits_GroupedDropDown1_elvBUGrp" style="width: 200px; height: 105px;" size="4" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <optgroup label="Business Units"><option style="color: red;" value="B_A234">A234 - Bahamas</option>
        <option style="color: red;" value="B_A235">A235 - Barbados</option>
        <option style="color: red;" value="B_A336">A236 - Bermuda</option>
        <option style="color: red;" value="B_A237">A237 - Bolivia</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497092/need-help-selecting-multiple-items-in-combobox-in-ie-using-vba  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987433/i-cant-select-multiple-items-in-dropdown-list-web-vba

Comment: Thanks Tim, but could not get either of these to work...possibly my lack of HTML knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to refer to the example below may help you to select the multiple items in the dropdown list.

VBA code:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim ie
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://Your_URL_here..."

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
 
    Dim selectElement As HTMLSelectElement
    Set selectElement = ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_listBusinessUnits_GroupedDropDown1_elvBUGrp")
    selectElement.Options(1).Selected = True
    selectElement.Options(4).Selected = True
    
    'ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can modify the code example as per your own requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of the options you want but not necessarily the position then you can do something like this:

```vba
Sub Tester()

    Dim IE As Object, slct As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'load HTML snippet from worksheet
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "about:blank"
        .document.body.innerHTML = Sheet2.Range("A1").Value
    End With
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    Set slct = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_listBusinessUnits_GroupedDropDown1_elvBUGrp")
    SelectOptions slct, Array("B_A235", "B_A237")
    
End Sub

'Given a select object `sel`, select any contained option which matches
'  `arrOpt` based on the option Value or Text (and deselect any other)
Sub SelectOptions(sel, arrOpt)
    Dim opt As Object
    For Each opt In sel.Options
        opt.Selected = Not IsError(Application.Match(opt.Text, arrOpt, 0)) Or _
                       Not IsError(Application.Match(opt.Value, arrOpt, 0))
    Next opt
End Sub
```